# Decode unicode string in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, json, nsstring

I got an app, where i download data through JSON. But when i am trying to show `NSStrings` i see something like this:

`\u041e\u041d\u0410!!!` etc.

How can I decode it into normal symbols?

---

in our team for this problem we create our own decoder

Comment: can you put your code where you initialize your NSString with data..?

Comment: Those are Unicode characters (in the Cyrillic range). Are you seeing these on a display (can the display cope with those characters?) or in a debugger watch window?

Answer (score 0):

You'll see `\u041e\u041d\u0410!!!` only in NSLog's console view.. just assign NSSTring's value to some UILabel or UITextField it will show properly

Answer (score 0):

If you log just for example nsdictioanry  you will see unicode `\u041e\u041d\u0410`, but if you will log NSString (objectForKey:@"key") it will be ok.